# hyperledger fabric 1.0 setup

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I'm trying to setup Hyperledger Fabric 1.0 as per the document at https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html on a Mac.
I have completed till the step "Generate the channel configuration artifact". After setting the ARCH_TAG environment variable,  I run the following command :

```
CHANNEL_NAME=<CHANNEL_NAME> docker-compose -f docker-compose-no-tls.yaml up
```

with the "CHANNEL_NAME" substituted with my channel name.

I get the following error :

> After 5 attempts, Peer 0 has failed to join the channel. Failed to execute End-2 End Scenario.

Can you please help me with this query.

Comment: I am able to run e2e flow mentioned in the above url on macOSx.. Could you please verify this on latest fabric commits now?

Comment: If you haven't already, please upgrade to Hyperledger Fabric v1.0.0, which was published July 11. You may have hit a temporary glitch.